# Setup a smtp relay to bypass outbound port 25 block

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I have a postfix mailserver in my own private network running. 
I recently had to change my Internet Provider and the new one is blocking port 25 outbound (I asked if they can unblock but answer was no). 
So receiving mails working but sending is blocked. 
I googled this problems and it seems many ISPs do that. 
However I did not find a "best practice" solution for it. 
I wonder because it must be a common problem for smaller companies. 
 
As a solution I want to setup a "smarthost": 
A postfix server running somewhere in the cloud (wihtout any portblocks) runs on port 2525 and relays all ingoing mails on that port to the internet on port 25. Also I setup my Mailserver to relay to the smarthost on port 2525. Is this solution possible? Are there others? How can I set up such a relay and configure it a way that it relays only mails from my mailserver? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible... You'll want your SPF records configured for your relay's IP address rather than your origin, in this case. Also be sure not to set up an open relay.
I doubt smaller companies have this issue as this restriction is mainly targeted at residential customers, not business customers.